# OSGi: org.osgi.framework.BundleExceptiom: Unable to resolve [16](R 16.0)

Tags: java, osgi

Im just began to learn OSGi. 
I wrote **HelloWorld** bundle:

```
    public class HelloWorld {
    public interface SayHello
    {
        void greeting();
    }

    public static class Greeting implements SayHello {
        @Override
        public void greeting(){
            System.out.println("Hello OSGi world!");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
}
```

And **HelloWorldActivator** bundle:

```
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class HelloWorldActivator implements BundleActivator {
    public void start(BundleContext ctx){
        ServiceReference ref = ctx.getServiceReference(HelloWorld.Greeting.class.getName());
    ((HelloWorld.Greeting)ctx.getService(ref)).greeting();
    }
    public void stop(BundleContext ctx){
        System.out.println("HelloWorld bundle has been stoped");
    }
}
```

HelloWorldActivator.mf:

```
main-class: HelloWorldActivator
bundle-name: HelloWorldActivator
import-package: HelloWorld
```

Uploaded it to Apache Felix(ver. 5.6.1):
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z81tW.png)
And when Im trying to start activator I get error message:
[screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEMms.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no package named `HelloWorld` for your bundle to import. So it fails to resolve. You have a class named `HelloWorld` but (1) I assume that class is in your bundle and (2) a class is not a package.

Your manifest is not a useful manifest for an OSGi bundle. `Main-Class` is meaningless to the OSGi framework. Your bundle is so simple, it only needs to `Import-Package` the `org.osgi.framework` package to have access to the `BundleActivator` and `BundleContext` types. And, since you have a bundle activator, you need to specify the fully qualified name of the class using the `Bundle-Activator` header.

I would suggest checking out the [OSGi enRoute](http://enroute.osgi.org) site for tutorials.

Comment: Actually if you look at his first screenshot, there are two bundles. One that contains HelloWorld, the other contains the activator. Not sure why that has been done.

Comment: Thanks I'll surely check those tutorial. 2 bundles need because I want one bundle to use methods from another.